# laravel5 ajax page pagination,how to change the button url

Tags: jquery, laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination

I use ajax to implement pagination. But I don't know how to change the Laravel pagination button `href`. Next page button always links to page 2.

My ajax code is below:

```
$('.pagination a').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( $(this).attr('href') != '#' ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                type: 'POST',
                data:{'_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                success: function(data) {console.log(data);
                    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    // 加载图书列表
                    var html = compiled_tpl.render(data);
                    document.getElementById('booklist').innerHTML = html;
                    $('.ajaxpage').html(data.render);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: it shows a lot button,like prev 4 5 6 7 8 9 next   ,thus there are too many to change,and i don't konw where is the start where is end

Comment: your loaded data must also contain a page value we can not see. `var page = $(this).attr("data-page");` and your next query is based on `page` . otherwise you will always have the same page

Comment: ajax response data is ok, my problem is the page in the view .i use $page->vender() to generate. so it can't verify ajax,and don't know which page the real is.

Comment: look at the response are there any variables pointing to the current page ?